# Creating a table with document.write in javascript

Tags: javascript

I seem to get nothing when I run my code, my code is supposed to create a 10 by 10 table. I am supposed to make it while using this form . And it is also supposed to use a for loop so that I dont have to repeat myself like 100 times.

```
document.write("<table>") 
document.write("<td>......") 
document.write("</table>")
```

This is my current code that I need to improve.

```
<script>

       var table = " ";
       var rows = 10;
       var cols = 10;
       for (var r= 0; r < rows;r++)
       {
       table += "<tr>";
       for(var c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
       {

      table += "<td>" + c + "</td>";
       }
       table += "</td>";

       }
      document.write("<table border=1>" + table + "</table>");

       }
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the last curly brace, and the line: table += "</td>"; should be table += "</tr>";

Comment: thanks for the quick and correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is faulty because you have an invalid curly brace at the end and you never end your first `<tr>`.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
   var table = " ";
   var rows = 10;
   var cols = 10;
   for (var r= 0; r < rows;r++)
   {
     table += "<tr>";
     for(var c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
     {
       table += "<td>" + c + "</td>";
     }
     table += "</tr>";
   }
   document.write("<table border=1>" + table + "</table>");
```

I changed the line

```
table += "</td>"
```

to:

```
table += "</tr>"
```

and I removed the curly brace at the end.

Here is a working example of the code, https://jsfiddle.net/h2qf9aj4/

Answer (score 0):

document.write() actually deletes everything then writes the text on the inside. So what you are doing is writing a page, deleting and writing something different, then writing another something...

What you can do is append by doing

`document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<table>"`

to create something at the end of the inner HTML body tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to document.write and concatenation:

```
<script>
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var rows = 10;
  var cols = 10;

  for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
    var row_create = document.createElement("tr");

    for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
      var col_create = document.createElement("td");
      row_create.appendChild(col_create);
    }

    table.appendChild(row_create);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);
</script>
```